# Vcpkg package not showing up on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, vcpkg

I have installed colmap via vcpkg and it's not showing up for me. It shows up on `.\vcpkg list` but not on Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

All of colmap's dependencies are showing up when I do `#include ""` and they also show up on `#include <>` along with many other libs, but no colmap can be found.

What can I do? Let me knowm if there's any other info I can give, I'm fairly new to C++ and Visual Studio, so there's only so much I know is important.

Comment: It sounds that the compiler can find header files, but the linker can't find the library? Could you please confirm? Or better yet - post the error message that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to include colmap. I had not payed attention to the debugger version I was using. It was set to x86 and my colmap was compiled at x64, so it would never show up on my VS2019!